# Searching returned records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

Consider the following table structure (not designed by me, and unchangable):

```
+---------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
|    the_id     |         field_name          |        field_value        |
+---------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
|      1        |           county            |       lincolnshire        |
|      1        |            type             |           hotel           |
|      2        |           county            |       lincolnshire        |
|      2        |            type             |          castle           |
+---------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Basically, I want to perform a search on this data, returning `the_id` of anything that matches the parameters I specify. So, for example I want to search for all `the_id` fields which have (field_name = county AND field_value = lincolnshire) AND (field_value = type AND field_value = castle). Thus, only 1 would be returned.

Essentially, I want to know if it's possible to perform a search on the returned results. Since the fields are completely separate entities linked by `the_id`, here's what I'm thinking in pseudo-code:

- Look up `county`
- Search for `the_id` and `type` in the results
- Return sub-set.

The problem is, I'm not 100% sure how this could be implemented in MySQL. Any feedback would certainly be gratefully received!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, the joys of using an SQL database as key-value stores, because it makes the DB schema so much simpler... first off, take the original designer of this system out back and beat them up with a rotten wet fish, preferably whale-sized, dropped from a great height.

then...

```
SELECT the_id, type, county
FROM (
    SELECT type_name.the_id AS the_id, type.field_value AS type, county.field_value AS county
    FROM yourtable AS type
    LEFT JOIN yourtable AS county ON county.the_id = type.the_id AND county.field_name='county'
    WHERE type.field_type = 'type'
) AS child
WHERE county='lincolnshire'
```

Comment: +1 for the fish assault - though nested selects won't work if you're also cursed with a really old version of MySQL ( < 5 IIRC).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.the_id
    FROM YourTable t1
        INNER JOIN YourTable t2
            ON t1.the_id = t2.the_id
    WHERE t1.field_name = 'county'
        AND t1.field_value = 'lincolnshire'
        AND t2.field_name = 'type'
        AND t2.field_value = 'castle'
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the Select and Where commands to run a query.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp